# I have problems printing from gedit in Windows

Tags: windows, gedit

Gedit in Linux works like a champ. For me, in two installations Gedit in Windows XP works well except that it will not print properly on HP LaserJets or Toshiba's laser printers. It will make a 90 page project out of two pages of text composed in gedit. It puts one or two confused lines of text at the top of a sheet and then ejects the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want Gedit on Windows? :/ (Notepad++ ? Cream ? Gvim ? Uhm.. and so on.)

Comment: Comment by John C in reply to @Fujishiro: Thank you for the advice. Gedit is there, my fingers know how to use it, I am used to it. It feels a lot like the 1983 DOS editor I used for fifteen years and finally abandoned. I am also a fan of vanilla ice cream. Any idea why it will not print properly from Windows?

Comment: No idea, but I'll check it out. Just give me some time. :)

Comment: What OS and which Gedit do you use? I tried 2.6.30 gedit and Windows 7, so far, so good. Maybe you could ALSO try a 2.6.31.xx build.

Comment: Found a good workaround. Try using "PDFcreator" (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) , a free application. Print to PDF and print out the PDF with adobe/foxit reader (sumatra is the worst when it comes to printing I WARNED YOU).

Comment: Shiki,

Thanks for the response and the suggestion.  I updated without a fix then tried the pdf route.  Turns out the image prointed to the pdf is exactly what comes out of the printer.  column about 25 chars wide, qprox 10 point font, eight lines of code long, wrapped at the 25 char line length.

Comment: Are you using a PCL or a PostScript driver in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

As Brian already mentioned in the comments, it might be a driver Problem. I´ve gotten the same issue with HP printers at work. Except in some other office applications like Office 2k3. Try changeing the driver from PCL5e to PCL6 or, if that doesn´t work PostScript. I don´t know yet, how to say which driver is needed before trying, but everytime I´ve got this problem this solution worked.

P.S.: if this is the correct answer, please vote up Brians comment ;-) it should be his reputation for mentioning it first.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/):

> Some of jEdit's features include:
>
> - Written in Java, so it runs on Mac OS X, OS/2, Unix, VMS and Windows.
> - Built-in macro language; extensible plugin architecture. Dozens of macros
>     and plugins available.
> - Plugins can be downloaded and installed from within jEdit using the
>     "plugin manager" feature.
> - Auto indent, and syntax highlighting for more than 130 languages.
> - Supports a large number of character encodings including UTF8 and Unicode.
> - Folding for selectively hiding regions of text.
> - Word wrap.
> - Highly configurable and customizable.
> - Every other feature, both basic and advanced, you would expect to find in
>     a text editor.